# Array of objects from REST in a GraphQL

Tags: graphql-js

Trying to wrap a RESTAPI with a graphQL but not able to put the response of API (an array of objects) in a graphQL Type. Can anyone help me with how to put an array of object in graphQL type and then resolve?

Comment: put the `resolve()` code please, and the `http` call too